# find initial guess for frequency of ~sin^2 data in python

Tags: python, fft

I am currently facing a problem of having to guess an already rather accurate frequency from data that I do not know the frequency of.
I know that the data should relate to `fit = A* sin^2(ω * t + φ)` since I know through other means that we are calculating a Rabi-frequency. I can take some guesses myself and try them out but I need to automate this as I will be generating way more of this kind of data in a bit, which would require a bit too much work when guessing manually.

Here is a plot of how the data with a fit over it looks.
[image: Data generated through complex system]

I tried some FFT stuff but even after subtracting the mean I am getting frequencies which are too high or too low resulting in the fit not working properly. As I also do not know how future data may look like (it all comes from a really complicated ODE solution that gets simulated over a lot of params in a very specific way) I absolutely need a rather robust solution.
My FFT implementation looks like this:

```py
def find_initial_freq(data, timestep):
    new_data = data-np.mean(data)
    fft_data = np.fft.fft(new_data)
    freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(len(data), d=timestep)
    peak = np.argmax(np.abs(fft_data))
    freq = freqs[peak]
    print(freq)
```

this results in a frequency of 0.11, the guess that works is about 0.35.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FFT will get you a frequency for sin(x) but your model function is sin²(x) which is proportional to sin(2x) + c.

Comment: Right thats something I missed but that gives a frequency of 0.22, still not close and in fact not converging to the fitted frequency of 0.356 (with guess 0.35)

Comment: How is your data sampled? The number of samples per period is most relevant here.

Comment: The data is obtained through an ODE system where i have 7 parameters. One of them is varied these varied parameters are created at runtime and are fully known. For this calculation the y-data is the end result of the integration of the ODE but squared. What i am plotting here is that y data over the varied parameter. They are equidistant  and can for example be calculated using `collect(range(0, plateau_cycle_end, length=amount))` (this is in julia since the entire simulation part is in julia for performance reasons). I simply save the data in csv files for python use.

Comment: I didn’t ask about how the data is computed, I asked about how it’s sampled. My question was mostly: how many samples per period do you have in that data? Also, please use `@cris` to tag me so I see your answer, thanks!

Comment: @CrisLuengo thats not something I know in general. The parameters I have prior knowledge to is the x-axis values and after computation the y axis values. How many x-values I then have in a period depends on the rabi frequency which I am trying to calculate here. Like at one point i could have 200 x-axis values per period and on the other hand i could have a few dozen. I know how many x-axis values i got overall but thats it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. You have enough samples that `argmax` gives a good estimate of the frequency. Are you taking into account that the period of sin(ωt) is not 1/ω but 2π/ω? Halving the period for the square sine, you’d have a frequency of ω/π. 0.11 π is pretty close to 0.35…

Comment: I did not take pi into account and you are perfectly right. This also works with other data i already generated. If you want you can post this as an answer and I will be accepting it. @CrisLuengo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76188435/find-initial-guess-for-frequency-of-sin2-data-in-python?noredirect=1#comment134366922_76188435) it seems that you are computing the frequency *f* as returned by `np.fft.fftfreq`, and using it as the radial frequency *ω* in the equation sin(*ωt*).

The two are related by *ω*=2π*f*.

Then you also need to take into account that squaring the sine doubles the frequency, so sin^2(*ωt*) has a radial frequency of 2*ω*.

Putting it all together, if you set *ω*=0.35, you should see a frequency *f*=2*ω*/2π=*ω*/π, which is pretty close to the 0.11 you measured.